# Homebrew Cask: List all formula available for installation

Tags: homebrew

After updating the local Homebrew cache by running `brew update`, I have been using `brew search` and `brew cask search` to list all the available formula for installation via **Homebrew Core** and **Homebrew Cask** respectively. Note that skipping the argument after `search` does the trick of listing all the formula available for installation.

While `brew search` still works, this is no longer the case with Homebrew Cask. Instead, now running `brew cask search` displays the explanatory text:

> Homebrew Cask provides a friendly CLI workflow for the administration
>   of macOS applications distributed as binaries.

followed by a list of available Homebrew commands.

What command one need to run, to get a list of all the formula available for installation via Homebrew Cask?

While it is still possible to navigate to:

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks`

and obtain the desired list, I am looking for a solution along the lines of previously working `brew cask search`.

I am running up-to-date version of Homebrew (Homebrew 2.0.4) on macOS Mojave 10.14.3 (18D109).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ brew search --casks`

---

Commands beginning with `brew cask` have been merged into `brew` (i.e. `brew search`, `brew cleanup`).

You can use the `--casks` flag in `brew search` to "display all locally available casks".

---

```
$ brew search -h
Usage: brew search [options] [text|/text/]

Perform a substring search of cask tokens and formula names for text. If
text is surrounded with slashes, then it is interpreted as a regular
expression. The search for text is extended online to homebrew/core and
homebrew/cask.

If no text is passed, display all locally available formulae (including tapped
ones). No online search is performed.

        --casks                      Display all locally available casks
                                     (including tapped ones). No online search
                                     is performed.
        --desc                       search formulae with a description matching
                                     text and casks with a name matching
                                     text.
        --macports                   Search for text in the given package
                                     manager's list.
        --fink                       Search for text in the given package
                                     manager's list.
        --opensuse                   Search for text in the given package
                                     manager's list.
        --fedora                     Search for text in the given package
                                     manager's list.
        --debian                     Search for text in the given package
                                     manager's list.
        --ubuntu                     Search for text in the given package
                                     manager's list.
    -v, --verbose                    Make some output more verbose.
    -d, --debug                      Display any debugging information.
    -h, --help                       Show this message.
```